# Conditional filtering of JSON before deserialisation to case class model

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

How to parse a JSON conditionally before deserialisation to the following case class:

```
case class UserInfo(id: String, startDate: String, endDate: String)
```

I have an implicit reads

```
object UserInfo {
    implicit val reads: Reads[UserInfo] = (
        (__ \ "id").read[String] and
        (__ \ "startDate").read[String] and
        (__ \ "endDate").read[String]
    )(UserInfo.apply _)
   }
```

I can parse the following json using above implicit reads

```
 val jsonString = """
{
       "users":[
          {
             "id":"123",
             "startDate":"2019-06-07",
             "endDate":"2019-06-17"
          },
          {
             "id":"333",
             "startDate":"2019-06-07",
             "endDate":"2019-06-27"
          }
       ]
    }"""

val userInfoList = (Json.parse(jsonString) \ "users").as[List[UserInfo]]
```

but sometimes the web service returns a JSON with no `startDate` and `endDate`, for example:

```
{
   "users":[
      {
         "id":"123",
         "startDate":"2019-06-07",
         "endDate":"2019-06-17"
      },
      {
         "id":"333",
         "startDate":"2019-06-07"
      },
      {
         "id":"444"
      }
   ]
}
```

How to conditionally parse json to ignore objects that don't have `startDate` or `endDate` without making those fields optional in `UserInfo` model?

Comment: Either you make those fields `Option`al (BTW date as `String` in case class seams weird), or you have to ignore `JsError` on JSON validation (not responsibility of the `Reads` in such case)

Comment: >BTW date as String in case class seams weird.

I just used for example purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid changing the model to optional fields we could define coast-to-coast [transformer](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonTransformers#Introducing-JSON-coast-to-coast-design) which filters out users with missing dates like so

```
    val filterUsersWithMissingDatesTransformer = (__ \ 'users).json.update(__.read[JsArray].map {
      case JsArray(values) => JsArray(values.filter { user =>
        val startDateOpt = (user \ "startDate").asOpt[String]
        val endDateOpt = (user \ "endDate").asOpt[String]
        startDateOpt.isDefined && endDateOpt.isDefined
      })
    })
```

which given

```
    val jsonString =
      """
        |{
        |   "users":[
        |      {
        |         "id":"123",
        |         "startDate":"2019-06-07",
        |         "endDate":"2019-06-17"
        |      },
        |      {
        |         "id":"333",
        |         "startDate":"2019-06-07"
        |      },
        |      {
        |         "id":"444"
        |      }
        |   ]
        |}
      """.stripMargin

    val filteredUsers = Json.parse(jsonString).transform(filterUsersWithMissingDatesTransformer)
    println(filteredUsers.get)
```

outputs

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "startDate": "2019-06-07",
      "endDate": "2019-06-17"
    }
  ]
}
```

meaning we can deserialise to the existing model without making `startDate` and `endDate` optional.

```
case class UserInfo(id: String, startDate: String, endDate: String)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Option` for this:

```scala
case class UserInfo(id: String, startDate: Option[String], endDate: Option[String])

object UserInfo {
    implicit val reads: Reads[UserInfo] = (
        (__ \ "id").read[String] and
        (__ \ "startDate").readNullable[String] and
        (__ \ "endDate").readNullable[String]
    )(UserInfo.apply _)
   }
```

This would work when `startDate` and `endDate` are not provided.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any way without making those optional.ie.e silently ignore those objects that don't have the `startDate/endDate.`

Comment: How would you expect it to be optional in the `Reads` if not `Option` ?

Comment: Mario answer worked for me 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56601051/4187091